# How to connect to Connect-MsolService with a different directory ( As global Admin )

Tags: powershell, azure

I have used below command to initiates a connection to Azure Active Directory in Power Shell.

**Connect-​Msol​Service**

I am required to set the password expiry to a domain but getting exceptions Such as

**Get-MsolPasswordPolicy** -DomainName YYYY.onmicrosoft.com -TenantId TYYYY-YYYY-YYY-YYYY-YYYY

ExtensionData                                    NotificationDays ValidityPeriod

-------------     RESULT             ---------------- --------------

System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject

Get-MsolPasswordPolicy : Access Denied. **You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet.**

At line:3 char:1

- Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName YYY.onmicrosoft.com -Tenant ...

**I am the global admin in the directory which created this b2c directory**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Googling `Access Denied. You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet` gives `About 93,600 results (0.55 seconds)`…

Comment: I am the global admin in the directory which created this b2c directory